# How to Cut String C++

Tags: c++, string, cut

Hello i want to cut string in this situation:

```
if (std::count(text.begin(), text.end(), ',') > 3 {
   //Cut String after 3 ',' 
}
```

text look like this:

"item1, item2, item3, item4, item5"

and i want this:

"item1, item2, item3, item4[Cut everything out on the right side >>], item5"
and return
"item1, item2, item3, item4"

Looking on first answer im looking for something like this(but working):

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    string s1 = "item1, item2, item3, item4, item5"; 

    if(std::count(s1.begin(), s1.end(), ',') > 3) {
        int comma = 0;
        int x = sizeof(s1);
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (comma == 3) {
                string sub = s1.substr(0, i); 
                cout << "String is: " << sub; 
            }
            if(s1[i] == ',') {
                comma++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [std::string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)?

Comment: What is your ***specific technical question*** about "C++", "string", or "cut"? "How do I write a program that does X", or "I want a program that does Y" is not a specific technical question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [std::string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

```cpp
#include <string.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    // Take any string 
    string s1 = "item1, item2, item3, item4, item5"; 

    // Start at position 0 to position of character ',' in "item4," 
    string sub = s1.substr(0, 26); 

    // prints item1, item2, item3, item4
    cout << "String is: " << sub; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Not quite, the length may vary, the only condition required is that the text should be written to the "x" comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    string s1 = "item1, item2, item3, item4, item5"; 

    if(std::count(s1.begin(), s1.end(), ',') > 3) {
        int comma = 0;
        int x = s1.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (comma == 3) {
                string sub = s1.substr(0, i-1); 
                cout << "String is: " << sub;
                return sub; 
            }
            if(s1[i] == ',') {
                comma++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `std::count()`, that is just wasted overhead. You are scanning the string twice when once would suffice.

Also, your use of `sizeof()` is wrong, you need to use [`std::string::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) instead. `sizeof(s1)` tells you the byte size of `s1` (ie, of the `std::string` class itself) at compile-time, whereas `s1.size()` tells you how many characters are in `s1` at runtime.

I suggest using [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) in a loop, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string cutAtNComma(const std::string &s, int n) {
    std::string::size_type idx = 0;
    while (n-- > 0) {
        idx = s.find(',', idx);
        if (idx == std::string::npos) break;
        if (n == 0) return s.substr(0, idx);
        ++idx;
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "item1, item2, item3, item4, item5";
    std::string sub = cutAtNComma(s1, 4);
    std::cout << "String is: " << sub;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/OuaGG6)

Alternatively, you can use [`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string cutAtNComma(const std::string &s, int n) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(s.cbegin(), s.cend(),
        [n](char c) mutable {
            if (c == ',') {
                if (--n == 0) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
    if (iter != s.cend()) return std::string(s.cbegin(), iter);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "item1, item2, item3, item4, item5";
    std::string sub = cutAtNComma(s1, 4);
    std::cout << "String is: " << sub;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/mwLYw9)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change little code as below.

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    string s1 = "item1, item2, item3, item4, item5"; 
    int comma = 0;
    int x = s1.length();
    bool flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (comma == 4) {
            string sub = s1.substr(0, i-1); 
            cout << "String is: " << sub;
            flag = false;
            return 0;
        }
        if(s1[i] == ',') {
            comma++;
        }
        else{
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        cout<<"String not contain more then 3 comma's \n String is :: "<<s1;

    return 0; 
}
```